# Encoding mixes up after replication

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

I have two MySql databases, on different servers.

I am replicating contents from DATABASE 1 to DATABASE 2.

**DATABASE 1**

Contains everything in UTF8_unicode_ci
Connection via php is done with `set_charset(utf8)`

**DATABASE 2**

Same as 1

**Replication**:

I am copying contents from DATABASE 1, to DATABASE 2, as follows:

Content is printed in file *JSONfile.php* with `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8')` and php `json_encode()`

Content is fetched via php with `file_get_contents(JSONfile.php)`, and `json_decode()``.

And then saved into *DATABASE 2*

*Sidenote*: I have no other way of replicating contents on the servers I'm using. No remote connections allowed.

**Problem:**

When I retrieve data from *DATABASE 2* and display them (always using meta charset utf8) there seems to appear some weird symbols, like this:

... autorizar la restauraciÃ³n de la pintura âLa Inmaculadaâ de Fran ...

Note: `mb_detect_encoding()` on this string returns: UTF-8

Just to try, I did `utf8_decode()` and it went into:

... la restauración de la pintura �La Inmaculada� de ...

Which fixes some of it and mixes strange with non-strange.

So, there must be an error somewhere.

Any idea to find the mistake?

**EDIT**: - Source of contents in DATABASE 1 -

All contents in DATABASE 1, are the result of a SCRAPE on different websites.
All scrapes are done opening the site with html meta charset utf8.
SOME of the sources have the &Xacute; entities, and some do not.

**EDIT 2**:

Converting to hex on **database 1**

DespuÃ©s de dos --> 4465737075c3a97320646520646f73

Converting to hex on **database 2**

DespuÃ©s de dos --> 4465737075c3a97320646520646f73 *(same as above)*

So problem is not in replicating from one database to another.

I keep investigating, and there is a very curious thing. On the database (both of them), when I access via phpMyAdmin there are some fields that show acute right, like "camión". But on the fields that have problems it shows encoded, like: DespuÃ©s

I don't know if phpMyAdmin is supposed to show the utf8 form or the human-readable one. But this difference between fields of the same table is surely the gate to finding the problem.

THE SHOW CREATE TABLE returns:

```
CREATE TABLE `contents_data` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `main_img` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `ContentsDataIdFK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `contents` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**EDIT**

Doing col(HEX) on field with string "Alcázar" returns "416c63e17a6172"

Very **curious** thing:

In the table shown right above, field VARCHAR encodes accents right, and the field TEXT, is giving the trouble, in ALL ROWS!

[image: More infos: See the change in accents, for fields VARCHAR and TEXT]

Columns are: "VARCHAR" and "TEXT" *(see more on the CREATE TABLE CODE ABOVE)*

**Note**: Same thing happens in every single row, regardless the source of the scrape.

Comment: The html entity `&oacute;` is unaffected by anything in MySQL, so we can ignore that case.  Except for the inconsistency in the database, and the inability to search (`WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`), there should be no issues.  I assume `scrap` should be spelled `scrape`?

Comment: @RickJames - Updated scrap to scrape (sorry for the mistake, and thanks.) - I edited the question again to show more useful information about the case. I am still looking into it. Thanks a lot for taking your time to read me. I sincerely appreaciate it.

Comment: Please `SELECT col, HEX(col) ... ` for the "camión" case.  If you have a single column in a single table with some `ó` and some `Ã©`, it will _not_ be easy to fix.

Comment: @RickJames Edited question again. Will read your edit to case 1 below now. Great article about Charset/Collate. A bible I'd say. Peace.

Comment: @RickJames I added an image (screenshot of PHPmyAdmin), to show what I mean. Which field is behaving wrong? The one showing human-result-readable-accents, or the one showing utf8-encoded-accents?

Comment: The `e1` in `"Alcázar" returns "416c63e17a6172"` is latin1 for a-acute.  (See the 8-bit Encodings near the end of the 'bible'.)  Hmmm... I should build a table of o-acute = A-tilde+sup-3 -- that is a utf8 encoding.

Comment: Years ago I screwed up and released a product unknowingly with "double encoding".  It took me a long time to figure out why, and how to fix it.  That 'bible' has been (and still is) my passion.  I continue to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably stored that "o-acute" when you had `set_charset` set to (or defaulted to) `latin1` and the definition of the column was `CHARACTER SET latin1`.

**Case 1**  That turned the `C3B3` (utf8 hex for o-acute) into Ã (hex `C3` in latin1) and ³ (`B3` in latin1).

`SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to see what is there now.  Also do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to get the `CHARACTER SET`.

(**Edit**) In this case *only*, do the [2-step `ALTER`](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixing_utf8_bytes_in_latin1_column), which goes something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other `...` have whatever else (`NULL`, etc) was already on the column.

Similarly, `TEXT` -> `BLOB` -> `TEXT`.

If `col` is in any indexes, you might want to `DROP INDEX` in the first `ALTER` and `ADD INDEX` in the second.  (This is for efficiency and possibly to avoid index limitations.)

**Case 2**  Or it might be "double encoded" -- the HEX won't be C3B3, but something longer.

Once you determined which case it is, we can discuss what to do about it.

[Blog with further discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, seriously. I edited my question to explain where sources come from, so let's say it's case 1, but not always. What you I do aboit it? Thanks again.

Comment: I added details for Case 1.

Comment: So, since field TEXT is giving all the troubles, and field VARCHAR is working fine in all rows, should I do TEXT->BLOB->TEXT, or is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you should do the 2-step ALTER on the TEXT field only.  Based on your Edit, maybe the VARCHAR can stay as is (even if it is latin1).

Comment: That's Spanish, correct?  Keep in mind that `latin1` will not get you past Western Europe.

Comment: I updated my blog with a new table.  Now we can search for `Ã³` and quickly find that it is the mis-encoding for `ó`.

Comment: Yes, it is Spanish. But since the beginning I am considering the possibility to add more languages in the future, which is one of the reasons why I decided to use unicode utf8. I applied the two steps alter, but still phpMyAdmin is showing one column with acute and one with "garbage". Will take a deeper look into Mr bible to see what I find out. [But when you said, varchar can stay as `latin1`, what do you really mean? I set everything to utf8 ever since I started]. Thanks again Rick, Will accept your answer this far, because it seems to be a particular case mine.

Comment: So now I changed my ways. I'm am converting the content to latin1 before inserting it. And, since I use SET NAMES utf8, MySql takes care of converting it into the right utf8 encoding. It's really weird, but it works fine now. Thanks again for your amazing help.